# Issue is request stops after sometime in Android Sencha app

Tags: sencha-touch

i have issue in sencha application in which i called window.setInterval function
to get user message after some specific time it is working in iPhone,Desktop(chrome)but On Android device request stops after sometime.And working properly on iPhone & Desktop.
So please help me out.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that on some Android devices, methods such as `setInterval` can be very unreliable and can often crash the browser completely.

To work around, I suggest you clear the interval every X seconds (depending on the amount of time you are using for your interval) and then restart the interval again.